# How can I send react-webcam video stream to a flask api for deconvultion?

Tags: reactjs, flask, websocket, socket.io, webcam

Basically I want to take a live stream and display the deconv-ed view of the 
I already have the deconv models btw and it is working with a local webcam stream with opencv (all within python)

Im just learning react so thats why this sort of connection/data transfer is new to me.

My research leads me to think I should make a WebSocket connection (socket.io most likely so I can relate with flask) but this is something im unfamiliar with too however I have found ways to send numerical data over a WebSocket connection so if I can figure out how to pipe the webcam stream I may be able to figure it out from there